# How to keep horizontally placed input fields always aligned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have forms on a web-page that have a distinct styling problem.

One of the requirements for the forms is that, whenever a form contains an error, the error message must appear between the label and the input field.  Whenever there is no error, there should only be a label and an input field. See the picture below:

[image]

The issue is that whenever the error message pops up, the input field is pushed down, and input fields in the same row are no longer aligned with each other.  I need input fields horizontally from one another to be aligned.  In other words, it should look like the following picture (ignore the silly watermark):

[image]

These are the main things that I need help figuring out:

1. Have the error message appear correctly between the label and the input field.
2. Keep the input fields aligned in a straight line at all times
3. Keep the label, error message, and input field in the same div as each other (they cannot be in separate rows)
4. Do all three of the above at the same time

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div>Label for first input field!</div>
          <div class="error">Label for first error message!</div>
          <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div>Label for second input field!</div>
          <div class="error">Label for second error message!</div>
          <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div>Label for third input field!</div>
            <!--<div class="error">Label for third error message!</div> -->
          <input type="text"/>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.error{
  color:red;
}
```

This is a link to a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/i0RR3XXeevh03TtoBP1M?p=preview

**EDIT**

This question is only concerned about the styling of these input fields.  This isn't the actual code that I'm trying to edit, but rather a minimal example which mirrors the problem I'm trying to solve.  There's no need to think about the mechanisms through which the error messages appear, but rather the styling only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something without the validation, I put an Error button for demonstration purposes. The markup has changed by merging the 2 `<div>` labels into a real `<label>`. Then added a `<br>` and a `<span>` that are toggled by one class `.none` Spread the window wider so you can see it function properly. Forgot to mention that the `<labels>` are `position: relative`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jxzoa5?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

i think you are going about this the wrong way. bootstrap has a validator form toggle. use it.

code:

```js
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="row">
  <form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
    <label for="Label1" class="control-label">Label 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Label1" placeholder=" " required></div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 form group">
          <label for="Label2" class="control-label">Label 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Label2" placeholder=" " required>
        </div>

     
        <div class="col-xs-4 form group">
          <label for="Label3" class="control-label">Label 3</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Label3" placeholder=" " required>
       </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-4 form-group">
      <br>
      <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT: TAKE TWO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.js" /></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
    function validate ( form )
    {

  if (form.Label1.value === "") {
    $('.alert').removeClass('hidden');
    form.Label1.focus();
    return false;}
  if (form.Label2.value === "") {
    $('.alert').removeClass('error');
     form.Label2.focus();
     return false;
  }  
return true ;
}
</script>
<style>
.error{
  color:red;
  display:none;}

</style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label for="Label1" class="control-label">Label for first input field!</label>
          <input type="text" name="Label1" id="Label1"/>
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in hidden">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <p>Error msg</p>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label for="Label2" class="control-label">Label for second input field!</label>
          <input type="text" name="Label2" id="Label2"/>
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <p>Error msg</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label for="Label3" class="control-label">Label for third input field!</label>
            <!--<label for="error" class="error">Label for third error message!</label>-->
          <input type="text" name="Label3" id="Label3"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>

      </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

this code does not seem to work in jsfiddle so i have mocked it up in my site. you can view it [here](http://www.rachelgallen.com/labels2.html)

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you, however I would have to consult with the designer in order to actually change the way the error messages appear.  They seem pretty set on the above design...